# How to choose Tomcat on Docker container using Tomcat for java

Tags: docker, ubuntu, tomcat, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

No information was found even after searching.
I don't know how to choose Tomcat on Docker container using Tomcat for java(Visual Studio Code's extension).
Somebody please tell me.

## My environment

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
editor: Visual Studio Code(version 1.30.2)
Tomcat for java: version 0.11.1
Docker: version 18.09.1-rc1, build bca0068

## Using Tomcat Docker Image

Tomcat Docker Official Images (tag 9.0.14-jre8)

## Make docker container command

```sh
docker run -p 18080:8080 -d --rm --name tomcat9-jre8 tomcat:9-jre8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see following page.
I solved it self so I put it together as a blog post.
http://j-levia.hatenablog.jp/entry/2019/01/14/104737